# Active Directory User Connected to Internet

Tags: windows, active-directory

Which event logs should be watched to see when an Active Directory user connects to internet? For example user is logged in to PC offline then connected to internet, is it possible to see user is connected to internet?

Comment: what OS? define "connected to the internet"

Comment: Windows OS, since user is AD user. With connected to internet I mean gets an IP address and is connected to network.

Comment: which windows OS (XP 2003 7 vista etc)

Comment: All windows versions starting from 2000/NT

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no such thing as "connected to the internet" from an AD perspective. You probably mean "using a browser", and that doesn't mean anything to AD either.

If you want to track user activity with regards to the Internet, you need either an agent on their machine that tracks everything, or something that sits on or near the internet gateway to capture or log all traffic, and also can query AD to see what users are associated with which local systems.

Comment: I mean when gets an IP, connected to network. Isn't this logged in event logs?

Comment: Not in any useful way. The workstation gets a DHCP-provided IP address on boot (if it's not static), but that has nothing to do with the user, and nothing to do with any internet activity.

Answer (score 2):

You may setup a proxy with integrated authentification against Active Directory and apply a GPO to enforce users using it. You'll then be able to process the logs of the proxy to see who's browsing Internet.